# Keep sort order of json columns in Laravel after inserting new Key Value pair

Tags: json, laravel

I have a key value pair that I am inserting into a model with the following:

```
public function addContactDetail(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        $contact_id = $data['contact_id'];
        $contact = Contact::find($contact_id);
        $details = $contact->details;
        $details[$data['label']] = $data['value'];
        $contact->details = $details;
        $contact->save();

        return response()->json($contact);
    }
```

After insert it sometimes puts it randomly in the middle of the object. How do I keep it at the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5 or greater version,

Try casting your json column into array in eloquent using mutators. like this.

inside your **Contact** Model

```
   protected $casts = [
        'details' => 'array',
    ];
```

By doing so, I guess you will get what you want. Try it and let me know